# ASP.NET MVC new Routes not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET MVC and I am trying to create a new route for a parameter like so:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "MarkOnline",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { offline = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

and here is my method call I am trying to use inside my API Controller

```
public void MarkOnline(string offline)
        {
        }
```

however what gets returned is my Entity Framework GetData method in the API Controller, which is this:

```
public IQueryable<VistaLCPreview> GetData()
        {
            return db.Data;
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's possible that your route is expecting 2 parameters {controller} and {id} and you're only providing it with 1 parameter called `string offline`. I'm not great at ASP.NET though so I could be wrong.

Comment: localhost/api/MyController?offline=xxx@xxx.com

Comment: localhost/api/MyController hits GetData

Comment: also localhost/api/MyController?offline=xxx@xxx.com hits GetData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, `GetData` is being called due to the fact that it has a prefix of `Get`. There's a convention that maps HTTP GET to functions prefixed with `Get`, HTTP POST to `PostXXX`, etc. `GetData` is being resolved by the default HTTP route, which specifies an optional `id` parameter and is not present in your expected `GetData` URL example (which is what you want there).

The `MapHttpRoute` from your example is not going to match, due to the `id` parameter in the `routeTemplate`, which has not been defaulted to `RouteParameter.Optional`. This route is actually unnecessary - You do not need to include query-string parameters in this route definition. Query-string parameters are simply mapped into the arguments passed into the actions (`offline` in your case).

Because `MarkOnline` is not prefixed with one of the HTTP Verbs as I mentioned above, it is not being matched by the default HTTP route. To fix your problem you simply need to do two things:

1. Remove the `MapHttpRoute` that you added. This is not needed as the default HTTP route I've already mentioned will cover your use-case.
2. Add the `HttpGet` attribute to your `MarkOnline` method. This will cause the routing to pick up `MarkOnline` when an `offline` query-string parameter is found, but call `GetData` when it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Your route is not configured correctly, you are not specifying the default action on your controller.

It should be something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "MarkOnlineRoute",
    url: "api/{controller}",
    defaults: new { action = "MarkOnline" }
);
```

But also notice that the order which you configure your routes is important, it should be located before the default route configuration:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

And as a reference, this is my test controller:

```
public class AvailabilityController : Controller
{
    // GET: MarkOnline
    public void MarkOnline(string offline)
    {
        //return Json(new { isOnline = true, name=offline }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

And it is called with: `http://localhost/api/availability?offline=xxx@xxx.com`